# Передача значений в input

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Допустим, есть инпут поиска, в который вводим какое-то значение (допустим 1). После подтверждения ввода на эту же страницу возвращается результат 1,2,3.

Как эти значения на этой же странице раскидать по инпутам, в див вставить получается..

Пример:

```
<input name="contract"><input type="button" id="but" value="Загрузить" OnClick="javascript:selectNet();">
    <div id="answer"></div>
    <input id="ass1">
    <input id="ass2">
    <input id="ass3">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function selectNet(){
        var contract = $('input[name="contract"]').val();
            if(!contract){
                    $('div[name="content"]').html('');
            }else{
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "test.php",
                            data: { action: 'showData', contract: contract },
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(responce){  
                    $('#answer').html(responce);
                    }
                    });
            };
    };
    </script>
```

А в test.php

```
 switch ($_POST['action']){

            case "showData":

    if (isset($_POST['contract'])){
    echo $ED;
    }break;
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте свойство `value` в элементах семейства `input`. Это свойство позволяет менять значение:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" value="">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#mytext').val("newval"); // устанавливает значение свойства `value="newval"`
```